# android 8.1.0 - unable to reinstall apk

Tags: installation, uninstallation, 8.0-oreo

Pixel 2, Android 8.1.0

I have an .apk which has been signed by a developer on our team. The first time I install one of the builds, it installs fine. If I uninstall the app and try to reinstall it again from the .apk, this is what happens:

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

I have tried clearing the data/cache of the Package Installer app as has been suggested elsewhere on google, but it did not help.

Any tips/ideas?

I should note that I am not an android developer, and our android developer does not know what's causing this or how to fix it. He is also a remote dev, so I can't just have him come have a look. I am not able to physically connect my phone to my computer, as it is a USB-C phone and I don't have a USB-C => USB-A cable.

**EDIT**
As requested in the comments, I am uninstalling the app by long-tapping the appicon and dragging it to the top of the screen where it says "uninstall". I have also tried uninstalling it from the app settings to the same effect (Settings -> Apps & notifications ->  -> Uninstall)

Comment: I've removed comments that are speculating on the business organisation and people's motivations outside the question. Let's keep things focused on solving the Android problem, not on blaming when we have none of the details.